# How to change/improve debugger UI in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, debuggervisualizer

I am looking for ways to create my own window to show different threads and other information in a different way. I found following is written at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview

"
Debug Adapter#

**VS Code implements a generic debugger UI and relies on debugger extensions and so called "debug adapters" to connect the debug UI to a real debugger or runtime.** A debug adapter is a dedicated process that communicates with VS Code through the VS Code Debug Protocol and can be implemented in any language.
"

Can someone guide me if it can be done by extension or by modifying the source code of VS code itself ?